# wordpress plugin not working in IE7 and 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

my weblog (http://blog.datisdesign.com) is working properly in Firefox and IE9, but in IE8,7 the slider plugin on top of weblog, is not working properly and shows me this error :

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice' 
jquery.js?ver=1.4.4, line 149 character 392
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Please show us the code that is generating the message.

Comment: website is online, you can check the script by IE debugger 
(http://blog.datisdesign.com)

Comment: To get the most out of Stack Overflow, you should consider posting the relevant code rather than asking others to go after the relevant code.

Comment: I know, but really i dont know which part of the code is making this error, all i know is that the line that i have put in the question ! sorry :(

Answer (score 3):

Because script 438 (whatever that is) tries to use Array:slice, which isn't implemented in versions of IE prior to 9.

Try adding this before your slider js file.

```
if (!Array.prototype.slice) {
    Array.prototype.slice = function (i, i2) {
        var cake = [];
        for (; i < i2; i++)
            cake.push(this[i]);
        return cake;
    };
}
```

It should fix it, no promises though.

If it's still not working, it must be String:slice. Try..

```
if (!String.prototype.slice) {
    String.prototype.slice = function (i, i2) {
        var cake = "";
        for (; i < i2; i++)
            cake += this.chatAt(i);
        return cake;
    };
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add and `if(!Array.prototype.slice)`-first, so that IF the browser supports it, it don't get overwritten.

Comment: Hmm. Given that the problem arises in jQuery my guess is that there is some bad parameters being passed in, maybe a arguments-array?

Comment: That's a good point, but then why would it break in other browsers? Plus, if you look at the source code, they never directly call `someArray.slice`, they save `var slice = Array.prototype.slice;` and use it with `slice.apply([], [1, 2]);`

Comment: isnt it because of two jquery is loding ?

Comment: @Datis Shouldn't be. jQuery only changes two global variables: `$` and `jQuery`, and when a different version is loaded, both of those variables get thrown out.

Comment: even the back to the top plugin is not showing and working in IE7,8 !